# clipping a UIView while zooming in

Tags: iphone

I have a custom UIView that draws some data and another more detailed view that draws some components of the first view.  What I want to do is after a gesture, zoom in, hide the first view, and then show the second view to give the user the context that they are zooming in deeper.

I thought I would start by doing something like this:

```
CGAffineTransform zoomTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(2, 2);
[UIView animateWithDuration:2 animations:^{
    self.chromoMap.transform = zoomTransform;        
}];
```

It does zoom in on that area by scaling that UIView.  However, I don't want my UIView to actually grow.  If my CGRect is {0, 0}, {100, 100}.  I want the frame of the UIView to stay the same, but just the contents inside it to scale by 2 to give that zoom effect.  How would I do that?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It seems I can just add another transparent UIView on top of it with  clip subviews enabled to get that effect.